# Getting signature from Outlook using python with Redemption RDO

Tags: python, email, outlook, outlook-redemption, rdo

I wrote a program that creates a mail in outlook and saves it in the .msg format. I want to add the signature of the user that is sending the mail (so the current account user) at the end of the HTMLBody. So far I haven't been able to find anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is an easy example of my code:

```
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")
session.Logon("Outlook")
signatures = session.Signatures
msg = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(r"test.msg")
msg.Subject = "test subject"
msg.HTMLBody ="<html><body> <b> this is a body</b></body></html>"
signatures.Item(1).ApplyTo(msg, False)
msg.SaveAs("file.msg")
```

It works now thanks for all the answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

By defualt, you can find user's signatures stored in the following folder on the disk:

```
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

It may contain the following files:

- .htm - This file is used when creating HTML messages.
- .rtf - This file is used when creating Rich Text messages.
- .txt - This file is used when creating Plain Text message.
- _files - This folder is used in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 to store supporting files for your signature such as formatting, images and/or business cards (vcf-files).

Basically you need to read an appropriate file on the disk and then instert the content to the mail item.